# How to read variables from serverside html in react

Tags: reactjs, html-rendering

I have `HTML` I'm getting from a server, it has some parts where the strings are (for example):

```
<p>Hello {applicant.first_name}</p>
```

How can I make `React` know that the string in the curly braces is a variable and thus read it as such?

The idea is when users save a template on a `WYSIWYG` editor, some of the contents are dynamic in nature such as an Applicants name so they write is as `{applicant.first_name}`, so where the `HTML` is being rendered is where the dynamic value should be read as a variable instead of a string.

[Here is the WYSIWYG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUind.png)

Comment: You can write it in this format `<p>{\`Hello ${applicant.first_name}\`}</p>`

Comment: i was able to figure it out. since the HTML returned from the server is a string. I used js replaceAll to find what I want to replace and then replace it with the dynamic value. Thank you!